# How to trigger an event using Parse for Android via push notification?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have successfully integrated Parse's push notification into my Android project. I would like some guidance on how I could trigger an event in my application if I receive a push notification that said "start"?

So if I get a notification and it only contained the value "start" it would then trigger an event to do something.

I am new to Parse and I appreciate the help guys!

Comment: Please help by answering this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412262/cannot-read-parse-push-notification-bundle-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow this steps:

If you want Normal push from parse.com

Steps:

After initializing Parse details,Add this

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, SampleClass.class);
```

Then in ur Manifest file ,add this

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then Go to parse dashboard, and send push manually inorder to check whether push is getting into ur phone. Use Json format like this,

```
{ "alert": "Notification", "title": "Push", "objectId": "objectId", 
 "objectType": "type", "action": "Your Action Name" }
```

### In phone,it checks whether json contains "alert" or "title" and shows standard push.

**To Get Custom Push Notifications...**

Specify like this in ur Manifest.

```
<receiver
    android:name="packagename.CustomReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="custom-action-name" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**action name is specified in your json .see the sample**

Sample JSON format is

**{ "title": "Custom Push-Android", "objectId": "***iuy", "objectType": "type", "action": "custom-action-name" }**

Based on this action name,BroadcastReceiver is called.

In parse dashboard ,u can manually test push notifications by setting text as message or Json format.

Then create ur broadcast class..

sample:

```
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 

{
 **public static final String ACTION = "custom-action-name";**


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

{

}
```

---

---

}

Comment: @KP_ Hello KP, i am trying to open play store when notification is clicked but it takes me to default activity and then i have to process the code. Is it possible to open the play store link instantly once notification is tapped?

Comment: @droiddev i think, using an intent and call that playstore link will load that page once notification tapped.Is that u required?

Comment: @KP_ Please help by answering this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412262/cannot-read-parse-push-notification-bundle-data