# Android parse sdk push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

Android parse sdk push notification is working on the emulator but when i run it on the phone using usb debugging, the push notification is triggered in the back-end and can be seen in my parse.com account but the phone doesn't receive the push notification.

```
public class Profile_InviteActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile__invite);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();    
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserProfile");
        Log.d("id",""+extras.getInt("fid"));

        query.whereEqualTo("fid", ""+extras.getInt("fid"));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(final List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
                    TextView location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_location);


                    name.setText(scoreList.get(0).getString("name"));
                    location.setText(scoreList.get(0).getString("location"));



                    ParseFile img1 = (ParseFile)scoreList.get(0).get("profileimage");

                   img1.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                        public void done(byte[] data,
                                ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Log.d("test",
                                        "We've got data in data.");
                                // Decode the Byte[] into
                                // Bitmap
                                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profimg);


                                image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                                        .decodeByteArray(
                                                data, 0,
                                                data.length));
                            } else {
                                Log.d("test",
                                        "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void inviteToTrain(View v)
    {
        Log.d("inviting","now");

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        //ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();      

        //installation.put("fids",true);
        //installation.saveInBackground();

        ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
        //pushQuery.whereEqualTo("fid", extras.getInt("fid"));
        pushQuery.whereEqualTo("fids", true);
        // Send push notification to query
        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query
        push.setMessage("Someone would like to join you at your event ");
        push.sendInBackground();
        Log.d("invited","now");
    }
```

}

Kindly help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to get push notifications,

You have to write broadcast receivers to handle that.

sample code :
After initializing Parse details,Add this

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, SampleClass.class);
```

Then in ur Manifest file ,add this

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then Go to parse dashboard, and send push manually inorder to check whether push is getting into ur phone. Use Json format like this,

```
{ "alert": "Notification", "title": "Push", "objectId": "objectId", 
 "objectType": "type", "action": "Your Action Name" }
```

More Details ,Refer

[How to trigger an event using Parse for Android via push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103477/how-to-trigger-an-event-using-parse-for-android-via-push-notification/20113584#20113584)

Comment: Thanks,but i have already done this.I am getting the push notification on my phone only if I create a new object like this ,every time.It doesnt work with the older registered ones.
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();      

        installation.put("fids",true);
        installation.saveInBackground();