# Cannot read Parse push notification bundle data

Tags: android, json, push-notification, parse-platform

I am trying to send custom data using the Parse push notification service, but while extracting from the Bundle always null values are returned.

**Custom Broadcast Receiver:**

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("Receiver","Invoked");
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Intent contentIntent = new Intent(context, MainPage.class);
    String alertMsg = bundle.getString("heading"); //never get this value
    String urlString = bundle.getString("dataString"); //never get this value
    contentIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, urlString);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            NOTIFY_REQUEST_CODE, contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    showNotification(context, notificationId, alertMsg, pendingIntent);
}
```

**Manifest Declaration:**

```
        <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.NotificationReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="link_notification"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**And i am sending the following JSON from parse dashboard:**

```
{ "dataString": "objectId", "heading": "type", "action": "link_notification" }
```

When i am logging the Bundle data i am able to see the **heading** and **dataString**, but cant access it. The bundle is always returning null.

Please help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The JSON will be in extra string `com.parse.Data`.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String heading = jsonObject.getString("heading");
        String dataString = jsonObject.getString("dataString");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, now i get it. To get your Json String, you need to do this :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
    String json = extra.getString("com.parse.Data");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because bundle data contains json object as string retrievable with key you can check at parse. Only then you have to parse this string with gson for example to get Java objects.

Comment: what is the name of the key in which the json string in paired with??